# HTML regex space

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to bind a regex to my HTML form for an EU bank account. So far, I was able to piece together that:

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}[000000000-999999999]{9}
```

Will let something pass that's for example UK123456789

But I also want to let it pass for UK12 2345 6789

How do I go about accepting a space at exactly those placements?

Comment: `[000000000-999999999]{9}` is like `[0-9]{9}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}[000000000-999999999]{9}"
```

This only accidentally does what you want. (`[000000000-999999999]` says "this character should be a `0` or a `0` or a `0` or ... a character in the range of `0-9` or a `9` or a `9` or ... a `9`.) The proper form is:

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}"
```

or more accurately:

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}\d{9}"
```

Now that we have something more rational, we can extend that to:

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}"
```

which allows optional whitespace at the specific locations.

If you want to allow just spaces rather than any whitespace character, you could do:

```
pattern="[A-Z]{2}\d{2} ?\d{4} ?\d{4}"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `'UK 123456789'.match(/[A-Z]{2} ?\d{9}/g);` Seems easier to read, but I don't know regex that well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That expression would certainly match against that string but that string isn't of a form that OP wanted. Also, the `g` is unnecessary as only the first match appears to be needed.

Comment: Just wondering, what form is missing in terms of what the OP wanted?

Comment: @JaredFarrish OP gave the examples "UK123456789" and "UK12 2345 6789" and then asked "How do I go about accepting a space at **exactly** those placements?"

Comment: Ahh, I see. I kept wondering why they were blocked up like that. LOL Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow an optional whitespace using `\s?`, though it'l make your regex a little longer. Below regex will allow both with or without whitespace ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rhTlKp/1))

```
\w{2}\d{2}\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}
```

But be aware that an european IBAN is longer than what you have posted - though I'm not sure how it is in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care where the spaces are, as long as there are 9 digits, you can remove all the spaces before checking:

```js
str = 'UK12 234 56789';
strToCheck = str.replace(/ /g, '');
validStr = strToCheck.match(/[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}/);
if (validStr) {
  console.log('Valid');
}
```

Comment: I notice the OP only wants to validate the spaces in specific locations, in which case my answer above is not correct, as it will validate with spaces in any locations in the string.  That said, in practice, I'm not sure why it would not be worth validating for spaces in unexpected locations,  provided there are enough letters and digits.